# Using Firebase in React Native shows a timer warning

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, websocket

I am using Firebase with React Native. Firebase shows me a timer warning as shown in the screenshot.

[image]

I read the following note in the [React Native troubleshooting](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/troubleshooting.html) guide.

> React Native implements a polyfill for WebSockets. These polyfills are
>   initialized as part of the react-native module that you include in
>   your application through import React from 'react'. If you load
>   another module that requires WebSockets, such as Firebase, be sure to
>   load/require it after react-native:

```
import React from 'react';
import Firebase from 'firebase';
```

I tried import React before Firebase. But, I still keep getting these timer warnings. The application does work fine. I keep getting multiple warnings at regular intervals. Any help would be well appreciated.

I am using the latest React Native and the warning comes in the Android emulator.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting a timer for a long period of time, i.e. multiple minutes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44603362/setting-a-timer-for-a-long-period-of-time-i-e-multiple-minutes)

Answer (score 19):

To sort this out all need to do is increase the value of the variable MAX_TIMER_DURATION_MS. Here are the steps:

1. Go to  node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/Timer/JSTimers.js
2. Look for the variable MAX_TIMER_DURATION_MS
3. Change 60 * 1000 to 10000 * 1000 , needed for firebase
4. Save the changes and re-build your app.

Comment: Is there a way to do this in the app source code? I sometimes have to remove the `node_modules`

Comment: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/97#issuecomment-427512040

Comment: This is not a solution. This just skips the error and requires changes to node_modules. The same can be achieved (and better) via `YellowBox.ignoreWarnings([`Setting a timer for`])`! However not using setTimeout within Firebase would be a real solution

Answer (score 1):

You could also switch to the native SDK's via a wrapper, it's generally much more performant as it's done natively so there's no timer warnings plus you get access to more than just the auth and database modules.

One such wrapper is [react-native-firebase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k7lYy.png) and it currently supports 10+ firebase modules:

[image: Supported modules table]

Disclaimer: author of the above.

Answer (score 0):

It's worked for me to changed to both variable's values.

const FRAME_DURATION = 100000 / 60;

const MAX_TIMER_DURATION_MS = 60 * 100000;

Answer (score 0):

Its worked for me also.

Go to node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/Timer/JSTimers.js

Look for the variable MAX_TIMER_DURATION_MS

Change 60 * 1000 to 10000 * 1000 , needed for firebase

Save the changes and re-build your app.

Answer (score 0):

It's worked for me to changed values.

```
const FRAME_DURATION = 100000 / 60;

const MAX_TIMER_DURATION_MS = 60 * 100000;
```

Comment: not a solution to the issue, just hides the warning basically.