# Setting a timer for a long period of time, i.e. multiple minutes

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native

**I want to use firebase auth with react native for `Login` and `Signup` but I got a yellow error:**

Setting a timer for a long period of time, i.e. multiple minutes, is a performance and correctness issue on Android as it keeps the timer module awake, and timers can only be called when the app is in the foreground. See (https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/12981) for more info. (Saw setTimeout with duration 111862ms)

**How Can I Fix That?**
I don't want to ignore that, I want to understand this error and solve that with the best and Standard way.
And This is my Code:

```
  export default class Login extends Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props)
            this.state = {
                email: '',
                password: '',
                response: ''
            }
            this.signUp = this.signUp.bind(this)
            this.login = this.login.bind(this)
        }
        async signUp() {
            try {
                await firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.state.email, this.state.password)
                this.setState({
                    response: 'Account Created!'
                })
                setTimeout(() => {
                    this.props.navigator.push({
                        id: 'App'
                    })
                }, 1500)
            } catch (error) {
                this.setState({
                    response: error.toString()
                })
            }
        }
        async login() {
            try {
                await firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.state.email, this.state.password)
                this.setState({
                    response: 'user login in'
                })
                setTimeout(() => {
                    this.props.navigator.push({
                        id: 'App'
                    })
                })

            } catch (error) {
                this.setState({
                    response: error.toString()
                })
            }

        }
        render() {
            return (
                <View style={styles.container}>
                    <View style={styles.containerInputes}>
                        <TextInput
                            placeholderTextColor="gray"
                            placeholder="Email"
                            style={styles.inputText}
                          //  onChangeText={(email) => this.setState({ email })}
                            onChangeText={(email) => {console.log(email);}}
                        />
                        <TextInput
                            placeholderTextColor="gray"
                            placeholder="Password"
                            style={styles.inputText}
                            password={true}
                            onChangeText={(password) => this.setState({ password })}
                        />
                    </View>
                    <TouchableHighlight
                        onPress={this.login}
                        style={[styles.loginButton, styles.button]}
                    >
                        <Text
                            style={styles.textButton}
                        >Login</Text>
                    </TouchableHighlight>
                    <TouchableHighlight
                        onPress={this.signUp}
                        style={[styles.loginButton, styles.button]}
                    >
                        <Text
                            style={styles.textButton}
                        >Signup</Text>
                    </TouchableHighlight>
                </View>
            )
        }
    }
```

I Reported to **Google Firebase Team**: (https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/97)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Josh Crowther Software Engineer at Google Said:

Using multi-step short duration setTimeouts doesn't actually fix the problem though. The Timer module still stays active and the app is still subject to the performance issues indicated in the warning. The issue here is that, we have use cases that require long timers, and react-native doesn't optimize for that use case.

So the net of all that is: This bug can't be fixed here we can only work around the error there are workarounds available (see [Setting a timer for a long period of time, i.e. multiple minutes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44603362/setting-a-timer-for-a-long-period-of-time-i-e-multiple-minutes)) that disable the warning. Doing the work to disable the warning in our code, doesn't help the issue (beyond disabling the warning), and adds additional SDK code/weight that is completely unnecessary.

I'd recommend chiming in on the issue mentioned above (i.e. [facebook/react-native#12981](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/12981)) if you aren't comfortable w/ the workaround provided

Answer (score 66):

To fix this issue...

1. Navigate to your `node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/Timers/JSTimers.js` file.
2. Look for the variable: `MAX_TIMER_DURATION_MS`
3. Change its value to: `10000 * 1000`
4. Save the changes (with auto format turned off) and re-build your app.

Found this answer on https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/97#issuecomment-485410026

Comment: This is just a temporary fix since when you change the `node_modules` files, it's only in your local env. since you're not suppose to commit the node_modules. So whenever a new developer setup the project, you will have to do it again.

And this is not a problem in the end. It's just a warning, and the Firebase devs already mentioned that they will not change it, since they want the devs to know that their library uses this timer related implementation. –

Answer (score 33):

Just add these two lines

```
import { LogBox } from 'react-native';

LogBox.ignoreLogs(['Setting a timer']);
```

Comment: This should be the recommended answer as other solutions have since been deprecated.

Comment: Ignoring logs would not actually fix the real problem.

Comment: @PulkitSharma agree with you.

Comment: This is not a problem in the end. It's just a warning, and the Firebase devs already mentioned that they will not change it, since they want the devs to know that their library uses this timer related implementation.

Answer (score 27):

### **Old**

This fixes the yellow box and the console log. It even fixes it for Expo.

Simply place the following script at the beginning of your codebase.

```
import { YellowBox } from 'react-native';
import _ from 'lodash';

YellowBox.ignoreWarnings(['Setting a timer']);
const _console = _.clone(console);
console.warn = message => {
if (message.indexOf('Setting a timer') <= -1) {
   _console.warn(message);
   }
};
```

---

### **New**

> `YellowBox` is deprecated and is replaced by `LogBox`

```
import { LogBox } from 'react-native';
import _ from 'lodash';

LogBox.ignoreLogs(['Warning:...']); // ignore specific logs
LogBox.ignoreAllLogs(); // ignore all logs
const _console = _.clone(console);
console.warn = message => {
if (message.indexOf('Setting a timer') <= -1) {
   _console.warn(message);
   }
};
```

Comment: For console, this should work: `console.ignoredYellowBox = ['Setting a timer'];`

Comment: Any alternatives without lodash?

Comment: It definitely needs cloned. There are many ways to clone objects. If you are using ES6, the following logic is equivalent `const _console = { ...console };`.

Comment: `YellowBox` is replaced by `LogBox` now.

Answer (score 11):

If you are using react-native `0.63` then do the followings in your `App.js` file:
import the `LogBox` from react-native

```
import { LogBox } from 'react-native';
```

and after all the imports in your `App.js` file just add this line, it is not necessary to add this line in any useEffect call.

```
LogBox.ignoreLogs(['Setting a timer for a long period of time'])
```

See the [docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/debugging#logbox) to learn more.

## OR

---

If you are using react-native `0.62` then do the followings in your `App.js` file:
import the `YellowBox` from react-native

```
import { YellowBox } from 'react-native';
```

and after all the imports in your `App.js` file just add this line, it is not necessary to add this line in any useEffect call.

```
YellowBox.ignoreWarnings(['Setting a timer for a long period of time']);
```

See the [docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/0.62/debugging#warnings) to learn more.

Answer (score 6):

Work around issue with yellow warning 'Setting a timer' .

copy & import following file (as fast as you can ;-))

```
import {Platform, InteractionManager} from 'react-native';

const _setTimeout = global.setTimeout;
const _clearTimeout = global.clearTimeout;
const MAX_TIMER_DURATION_MS = 60 * 1000;
if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
    // Work around issue `Setting a timer for long time`
    // see: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/97
    const timerFix = {};
    const runTask = (id, fn, ttl, args) => {
        const waitingTime = ttl - Date.now();
        if (waitingTime <= 1) {
            InteractionManager.runAfterInteractions(() => {
                if (!timerFix[id]) {
                    return;
                }
                delete timerFix[id];
                fn(...args);
            });
            return;
        }

        const afterTime = Math.min(waitingTime, MAX_TIMER_DURATION_MS);
        timerFix[id] = _setTimeout(() => runTask(id, fn, ttl, args), afterTime);
    };

    global.setTimeout = (fn, time, ...args) => {
        if (MAX_TIMER_DURATION_MS < time) {
            const ttl = Date.now() + time;
            const id = '_lt_' + Object.keys(timerFix).length;
            runTask(id, fn, ttl, args);
            return id;
        }
        return _setTimeout(fn, time, ...args);
    };

    global.clearTimeout = id => {
        if (typeof id === 'string' && id.startsWith('_lt_')) {
            _clearTimeout(timerFix[id]);
            delete timerFix[id];
            return;
        }
        _clearTimeout(id);
    };
}
```

Comment: Needs more information; what does this code do?

Comment: It splits the time duration, into multiple timers that are smaller than 60seconds

Comment: Will make the warning disappear

Answer (score 4):

```
import { YellowBox } from 'react-native';

construct() {
    YellowBox.ignoreWarnings(['Setting a timer']);
}
```

This ignores the warning for me. You should add this to the constructor of every page that shows the warning.

Ignoring it is not the best approach, but if you're using Firebase Realtime Database. [They are looking](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/97) into solving this issue with their library, even though the issue is 2 years old.

Answer (score 4):

What I did and it's working with me but still I don't knwo if it's a good practice or not

Navigated to file

> node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js

there is a function `const MAX_TIMER_DURATION_MS = 60 * 1000` and I increased the time to be 60 * 100000 and it stopeed appearing

Answer (score 3):

I got the same issue and I think it's problem of firebase web SDK so I decided to drop firebase web SDK because it runs in js thread, not react-native thread.

And I found [react-native-firebase](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase) . It's better than firebase web SDK with higher performance and this issue went away

Comment: Did you check the source code of this lib ? The warning isnt shown because the author did use the trick mentionned above :D https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=ignoredYellowBox&type=

Comment: @Sephy: I have not checked the source code of lib yet but I'm using it for my app and it works well.And I also didn't do the trick as you found.

Comment: Some people need to use the javascript firebase with React Native, for example, Expo doesn't support react-native-firebase.

Comment: https://rnfirebase.io/ need to link native module for android and IOS, so it cannot work on Expo. You need to remove Expo from your project by command "npm run eject"

Answer (score 2):

Facing the same issue.. Seems like, we'd have to hide the warning for the time being. Here's the shortest way to do it:

```
componentDidMount() { console.disableYellowBox = true; ... }
```

Comment: Hiding the problem won't cease it from happening. You may have problems in the future for not handling properly all the warnings you have.

Answer (score 2):

For firebase/firestore users: Rather than trying to mask / hide the warning, I simply reverted to the REST API. Works like a charm :)

- I'm using the `firebase` node package for auth
- I'm using regular HTTP calls for firestore (which also gets rid of the otherwise necessary `atob` and `bto` hacks)

Snippet below just uses an HTTP client (https://github.com/hardcodet/httpclient-js), you can use whatever works for you (e.g. fetch or axios).

```
// Firebase App (the core Firebase SDK) is always required and
// must be listed before other Firebase SDKs
import * as firebase from "firebase/app";
import "firebase/auth";
import {LoginStatus} from "./LoginStatus";
import {auth, User} from "firebase";
import {ApiResponse, DelegateBearerAuthClient, HttpClient} from "@hardcodet/httpclient";
import {Env} from "../../Env";



export class FirebaseClient {

    /**
     * Creates a simple API client to use with Firestore.
     * We don't want to use the JS package's implementation since it has issues with
     * long-running timers - see https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/97
     * @param idToken The user's ID token as retrieved through firebase auth
     */
    private static getFirestoreClient(idToken: string) {
        const projectId = Env.firebaseProjectId;
        const baseUri = `https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/${projectId}/databases/(default)/documents/`

        const authClient = new DelegateBearerAuthClient(async () => idToken);
        return new HttpClient(baseUri, {authClient});
    }


    /**
     * Use firebase auth for login etc. because lazy.
     */
    public static async userLogin(email: string, password: string): Promise<User> {
        try {
            const credentials: firebase.auth.UserCredential = await auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
            return credentials.user;
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
            return undefined;
        }
    }


    private static resolveStatus(errorCode: string): { user: User, status: LoginStatus } {
        switch (errorCode) {
            case "auth/invalid-email":
                return {user: undefined, status: LoginStatus.InvalidEmailAddress};
            case "auth/user-not-found":
                return {user: undefined, status: LoginStatus.UnknownUserId};
            case "auth/wrong-password":
                return {user: undefined, status: LoginStatus.WrongPassword};
            case "auth/email-already-in-use":
                return {user: undefined, status: LoginStatus.EmailAddressAlreadyInUse};
            case "auth/weak-password":
                return {user: undefined, status: LoginStatus.WeakPassword};
            case "auth/user-disabled":
                return {user: undefined, status: LoginStatus.UserDisabled};
            case "auth/expired-action-code":
                return {user: undefined, status: LoginStatus.InvalidActionCode};
            default:
                return {user: undefined, status: LoginStatus.Undefined};
        }
    }


    /**
     * Resolve the user's keys from the backend.
     */
    public static async getSomeUserData(firebaseUserId: string, idToken: string): Promise<...> {

        const client: HttpClient = FirebaseClient.getFirestoreClient(idToken);

        // userData here is the name of my collection in firestore. i'm using the user ID as the document ID
        var result = await client.getAs<any>(`userData/${firebaseUserId}?key=${Env.firebaseApiKey}`);
        if (result.success) {
            const json = result.value;
            const foo = json.fields.foo.stringValue;
            const bar = json.fields.bar.stringValue;
            return ...
        } else {
            if (result.notFound) {
                // that document with that key doesn't exist
                console.warn("no document with key " + firebaseUserId);
                return undefined;
            }
            throw result.createError();
        }
    }


    public static async writeSomeData(idToken: string, firebaseUserId: string, foo: string, bar: string): Promise<...> {

        const data = {
            "fields": {
                "foo": {
                    "stringValue": foo
                },
                "bar": {
                    "stringValue": bar
                }
            }
        };

        // again, just do an HTTP post, use the firebase user ID as the document key
        const client: HttpClient = FirebaseClient.getFirestoreClient(idToken);
        const result: ApiResponse = await client.post(`userData?documentId=${firebaseUserId}&key=${Env.firebaseApiKey}`, data);

        if (result.success) {
            return ...
        } else {
            throw result.createError();
        }
    }


    /**
     * Gets the currently logged in user, if any.
     */
    public static getCurrentUser(): User {
        return auth().currentUser;
    }



    public static async sendPasswordReset(email: string): Promise<LoginStatus> {

        try {
            await auth().sendPasswordResetEmail(email);
            return LoginStatus.Success;
        } catch (error) {
            return FirebaseClient.resolveStatus(error.code).status;
        }
    }


    /**
     * Clears the current user from the session.
     */
    public static async signOut() {
        await auth().signOut();
    }
}
```

Note the `idToken` parameter - this is simply the ID token you get off the firebase `User` class:

```
        const user: User = await FirebaseClient.userLogin("me@domain.com", "mypassword");

        const idToken= await user.getIdToken(false);
        const data = await FirebaseClient.getSomeUserData(user.uid, idToken);
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to use the react-native-ignore-warnings module.

https://github.com/jamrizzi/react-native-ignore-warnings

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-ignore-warnings

This even works for Expo apps.

You would use it the following way . . .

```
import ignoreWarnings from 'react-native-ignore-warnings';

ignoreWarnings('Setting a timer');
```

can run with android too..?

Comment: Good God, why does that exist?!

Comment: Well specifically to ignore unavoidable firebase warnings in expo that clog the logs and make it difficult to debug the application

Comment: In which file should this go?

Comment: It should go at the begging of your program, so probably the index.js file in the root.

Answer (score 1):

In `login()`, your `setTimeout()` call is missing an interval value.  As a general, browsers now do not fire timeouts/intervals if the window/tab is in the background, or at least they are not expected to be timely.  This is to prevent abusive script behaviour, and to reduce power consumption by scripts that may be polling.

Your code should work in principle, if the user switches away from the window whilst the timer is running, it will complete when they return.  This is probably what you want from a UX point of view, because the users sees the transition, rather than it happening in the background when they are not looking. It helps them maintain mental context.

The yellow box is because you are setting an excessively long timer according to the message (nearly two minutes) and that is unlikely to be contextually what you want. The JS environment is warning you that what you are doing it not likely what you intend.  You can mute the warning if it is what you want.

Answer (score 1):

I think the most close-aide solution to this problem (until RN fixed this internally) is the solution mentioned [here](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/97#issuecomment-322742551).

```
// add this code to your project to reset all timeouts
const highestTimeoutId = setTimeout(() => ';');
for (let i = 0; i < highestTimeoutId; i++) {
    clearTimeout(i); 
}
```

Being used that - against Firebase call I still receive one yellow box warning (on settimeout), but any concurrent warnings never come thereafter. I'm not sure calling this at which point may not trigger the only warning also, but not any concurrent warning throws anymore after Firebase's `async` calls.

Comment: This is not a good solution. It will disable any pending timeouts you've created, which could have significant effects on your program. In this particular firebase case, it will disable getting the new refresh tokens, so users will be forced to log back in again.

Answer (score 1):

I'm disabling the warning with this code

```
import { YellowBox } from 'react-native';
YellowBox.ignoreWarnings(['Setting a timer']);
```

Comment: OP wrote in the question: "I don't want to ignore that, I want to understand this error and solve that with the best and Standard way."

Comment: this is now deprecated, use LogBox instead