# React Native Clock - setting a timer for a long period of time

Tags: react-native

I am trying to create an app with React Native that needs to show a clock on screen (only minutes need to update correct, not seconds). The app may be on screen (visible) for multiple minutes.

Is there a correct way to do this, as so far every way I have tried brings up 'Setting a timer for a long period of time, i.e. multiple minutes, is a performance and correctness issue on Android...'.

How can I accomplish a simple clock with correctness and minimal effect on battery etc.

The clock works fine, I just get the warning. I've tried various methods including regular setTimeout/Interval and this.setTimeout, also react-native-background-timer.

I also only need to update the clock when this screen comes back into view so I cancel the timer on componentDidUnmount. The clock only needs to update on minutes, not seconds, and doesn't need to be 100% accurate i.e. a small delay until the minutes updates is fine.

Thanks!

Code:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {View, Image, AppState} from 'react-native';
import {Text} from 'react-native';
import Styles from '../../styles/Styles';
import BackgroundTimer from 'react-native-background-timer';

/*
 Digital Clock
 */

export default class UIDigitalClock extends Component {

    // Render -----------------

    render() {

        var label = this.formatAMPM(this.state.time);

        return (
            <Text style={[Styles.h0,{fontSize:80,opacity:0.7}]}>{label}</Text>
        );
    }

    formatAMPM(date) {
        var hours = date.getHours();
        var minutes = date.getMinutes();
        var ampm = hours >= 12 ? 'pm' : 'am';
        hours = hours % 12;
        hours = hours ? hours : 12; // the hour '0' should be '12'
        minutes = minutes < 10 ? '0'+minutes : minutes;
        var strTime = hours + ':' + minutes;
        return strTime;
    }

    //--------------------------------


    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            time: new Date()
        }

    }

    timer = null;

    componentWillMount() {
        AppState.addEventListener('change', this.handleAppStateChange);
        console.log('Digital Clock - Mount - Start');
        this.startTimer();
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        AppState.removeEventListener('change', this.handleAppStateChange);
        this.stopTimer();
    }

    startTimer() {
        return;
        if (this.timer>0) return;   // Already started
        this.timer = BackgroundTimer.setInterval(() => {
            // this will be executed every 200 ms
            // even when app is the the background
            this.updateTime();
        }, 1000);
    }
    stopTimer() {
        console.log("Digital Clock - stop ");
        if (this.timer>0) {
            BackgroundTimer.clearInterval(this.timer);
            this.timer = -1;
        }
    }

    handleAppStateChange = (appState) => {
        console.log("Digital Clock app state: "+appState);
        if (appState=='background') {
            console.log('Digital Clock - App in Background - Stop');
            this.stopTimer();
        } else if (appState=='active') {
            console.log('Digital Clock - App is Active - Start');
            this.startTimer();
        }

    }

    updateTime() {
        let time = this.state.time;
        let newTime = new Date();
        // TODO - check if the app is in the foreground
        console.log('Digital Clock - Tic ');
        // Only update the render when the time changes...
        if (!time || (time.getMinutes() != newTime.getMinutes() || time.getHours() != newTime.getHours())) {
            console.log('Digital Clock - Time changed (mins/hours) - updating...');
            this.setState({time: newTime});
        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Later.js](https://bunkat.github.io/later/). You could set a schedule to fire every minutes

```
const schedule = later.parse.text('every 1 mins');
later.date.localTime();

later.setTimeout(<your function>, schedule);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this issue here can help people:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/49886834/12056841

> This bug can't be fixed here we can only work around the error there are workarounds available that disable the warning