# React Native Warning: "Setting a timer for a long period of time...". How to locate cause?

Tags: android, node.js, reactjs, react-native

Everything on iOS works fine. On Android I am getting the warning "Setting a timer for a long period of time, i.e. multiple minutes, is a performance and correctness issue on Android as it keeps the timer module awake, and timers can only be called when the app is in the foreground. See https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/12981 for more info. (Saw setTimeout with duration 589668ms)"

I don't use any timers in my app so I am assuming this is from an NPM module I have installed. How can I determine which one is causing this?

I see that I can [ignore the waring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44603362/setting-a-timer-for-a-long-period-of-time-i-e-multiple-minutes), but I would like to report the issue to the module maintainer.

Answer (score 7):

This is a warning that certain javascript dependencies will raise on react-native due to an issue on their side and must be solved in react-native's codebase but is not a cause for concern. If it bothers you just add `console.ignoredYellowBox = ['Setting a timer'];`. To find out which dependency is causing it you must debug the app with chrome and ensure sourcemaps are enabled.

Comment: Put it ay the beginning of your script

Answer (score 1):

The https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/12981 said you need edit server file. In you index.js file

```
var server = require('https').Server(options, app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
```

change to

```
var server = require('https').Server(options, app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server,{pingTimeout: 30000});
```

and then run `forever restartall` to restart

Answer (score 1):

This link will help you
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/12981#issuecomment-499827072

The code (from here: firebase/firebase-js-sdk#97 (comment)) simply wraps the setTimeout (global) function to prevent it from being used with a long period.

In our modified global.setTimeout function, if the duration time is greater than the threshold MAX_TIMER_DURATION_MS, we save an id in a local map (timerFix) and then call runTask which splits the duration time into smaller values. runTask sets a timeout (using the original _setTimeout) with the smaller chunks that will be continuously executed until waitingTime is too small. When waitingTime is small enough, we call React Native's runAfterInteractions for a smooth execution, and, at the same time, we remove the id entry from our local map because we won't be calling _setTimeout again in this case. Note that afterTime is fed into _setTimeout to prevent it from being called with a long period.

Otherwise, in our modified global.setTimeout function, if the duration time is smaller than the threshold MAX_TIMER_DURATION_MS, we directly call the global setTimeout (saved in _setTimeout).

The global clearTimeout is also wrapped to perform a cleanup process by removing the id from the local map.

Answer (score 1):

For firebase/firestore users: I simply reverted to using the REST endpoints directly for firestore calls rather than trying to mask the warning. Since I only needed auth and firestore, that solved my problems rather easily. Snippet here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/62446792