# Does react-native-firebase package handle the "Setting a timer for a long period of time is a performance and correctness issue" warning?

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I have been getting a lot of these yellow warnings in my app. Especially in parts of the code where I use firebase/firestore SDK:

**Setting a timer for a long period of time, i.e. multiple minutes, is a performance and correctness issue on Android as it keeps the timer module awake, and timers can only be called when the app is in the foreground. See https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/12981 for more info. (Saw setTimeout with duration 529480ms)**

I have read a couple of threads on the subject:

[React Native Warning: "Setting a timer for a long period of time...". How to locate cause?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46513408/react-native-warning-setting-a-timer-for-a-long-period-of-time-how-to-loc?rq=1)

[Setting a timer for a long period of time, i.e. multiple minutes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44603362/setting-a-timer-for-a-long-period-of-time-i-e-multiple-minutes)

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/12981

Some say it is nothing, just suppress the warning. Some say it is very important and should be handled.

In some of these threads, some people mention that this package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-firebase actually can solve the problem.

1- What type of problems will these timers cause if I just suppress them and do nothing?

2- What is the exact problem here? Battery drainage of my mobile react-native app?

3- Message says "*it keeps the timer module awake, and timers can only be called when the app is in the foreground*" what is the problem indicated here? So the app keeps the timer module awake even if it is in the background? And there is no use to keep it awake since timers can't be called when the app is in the background? And this awake timer module drains the battery?

4- What size of a performance/battery drainage effect are we talking about here?

5- Would that be possible to turn off/on these timers manually in the code as the app is backgrounded/foregrounded? And that would be an actual solution to this?

6- Do you think/know if this react-native-firebase package really handles this situation?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: did you find the solution?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't see that error popping up on the native package. However, I felt it was really heavy for what I needed, so I simply reverted to using the REST endpoints directly for firestore calls rather than trying to mask the warning. Since I only needed auth and firestore, that solved my problems rather easily. Snippet here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/62446792