# How do I turn off warnings in Android Virtual Device?

Tags: android, react-native, android-virtual-device

I get these yellow warning boxes on the bottom of my AVD. How do I turn that off, because it is really annoying.

Image of an error:
[image]

Comment: Can we get a snapshot of these warnings please?

Comment: I updated the post.

Comment: i think it's react native code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting a timer for a long period of time, i.e. multiple minutes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44603362/setting-a-timer-for-a-long-period-of-time-i-e-multiple-minutes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In RN>55(or 54 maybe) you can ignore warnings by this code:

```
import { YellowBox } from 'react-native';

  constructor(props, context) {
     ...
     YellowBox.ignoreWarnings(['Setting a timer for a long']);
  }
```

put this in `index.js` constructor and type some beginning words of warning error.

Answer (score 6):

You can add

```
console.disableYellowBox = true;
```

in your react-native project, as I have added it in my app.js right after all the imports
this may help you with solving the below yellow box warning

Answer (score 1):

`YellowBox` is now deprecated in favour of `LogBox`. You need to add this to your `index.js` -

```
import { LogBox } from "react-native";
LogBox.ignoreLogs([
  "Setting a timer",
  "Log warning #2",
  "Log warning #3,
]);
```