# How to upload an image using expo-image-picker in react native

Tags: react-native, expo

I want to know how to upload an image using expo-image-picker.

Currently my expo project has this warning :

```
Setting a timer for a long period of time, i.e. multiple minutes, is a performance and correctness issue on android as it keeps the timer module awake, and the timers can only be called when the app is in the foreground.
```

I'm looking for an answer that describes how to upload an image and fix this warning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you can find answer for your second question about warning ["Setting a timer for a long period of time..".](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44603362/setting-a-timer-for-a-long-period-of-time-i-e-multiple-minutes)

For the your first question the best is to take a look at documentation:
https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/imagepicker/

Here you can find all possible methods and this example of how to pick the image:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Button, Image, View } from 'react-native';
import * as ImagePicker from 'expo-image-picker';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';
import * as Permissions from 'expo-permissions';

export default class ImagePickerExample extends React.Component {
  state = {
    image: null,
  };

  render() {
    let { image } = this.state;

    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
        <Button
          title="Pick an image from camera roll"
          onPress={this._pickImage}
        />
        {image &&
          <Image source={{ uri: image }} style={{ width: 200, height: 200 }} />}
      </View>
    );
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getPermissionAsync();
    console.log('hi');
  }

  getPermissionAsync = async () => {
    if (Constants.platform.ios) {
      const { status } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.CAMERA_ROLL);
      if (status !== 'granted') {
        alert('Sorry, we need camera roll permissions to make this work!');
      }
    }
  }

  _pickImage = async () => {
    let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
      mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.All,
      allowsEditing: true,
      aspect: [4, 3],
      quality: 1
    });

    console.log(result);

    if (!result.cancelled) {
      this.setState({ image: result.uri });
    }
  };
}
```

Comment: I have tried this but the result is Promise {
  "_40": 0,
  "_55": null,
  "_65": 0,
  "_72": null,
}

Comment: And could you let me know how to upload the image to firebase storage?

Comment: You need to use more google :) I was using this tutorial for uploading to firebase storage: https://medium.com/@joananespina/uploading-to-firebase-storage-with-react-native-39f4a500dbcb

Comment: this tutorial? medium? I tried already, but it doesn't work for me~

Answer (score 0):

It's Just a warning,You can ignore that by following Code

```
import { YellowBox } from 'react-native';

YellowBox.ignoreWarnings(['Setting a timer']);//Add this to constructor
```

That's it,Ignore it

it's fixed for me