# React native, setTimeout gives weird warning when called inside useEffect

Tags: reactjs, react-native, settimeout, use-effect

I ultimately want to display a modal to the user if a certain condition is met after X seconds of the app execution.

However, I keep getting a warning about setting a timer for a long period of time (a few minutes) on android, but my timer only has a few seconds.

```
const surveyCheckTime = 3000; // X = 3 seconds

const App = () => {
  // First Time Modal State
  const [surveyVisibility, setSurveyVisibility] = useState(false);
  const handleSurveyOpen = () => {
    setSurveyVisibility(true);
  };
  const handleSurveyClose = () => {
    setSurveyVisibility(false);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const timer = setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('0:FROM_APP: Checking for condition: ');
      getData().then(
        keyValue => {
          console.log('0:FROM_APP: Completion status: ', keyValue);
          if (keyValue === 'false' || keyValue === undefined) {
            handleSurveyOpen();
          }
        },
        error => {
          // console.log('Survery_Error: ', error);
        },
      );
    }, surveyCheckTime);

    return () => clearTimeout(timer);
  }, []);

  return (
      <View>
         ...
        <SurveyModal
          surveyVisibility={surveyVisibility}
          handleSurveyClose={handleSurveyClose}
        />
      </View>
  )
```

getData() is an async function returning keyValue as promise.

```
export const getData = async (myKey = 'alreadyOpened') => {
  try {
    const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem(`@${myKey}`);
    if (value !== null) {
      // value previously stored
      // console.log('FROM__getData: Stored previously: ', value);
      return value;
    }
  } catch (e) {
    // error reading value
    console.log('ERROR:FROM__getData: Cannot read: ', e);
    return 'fasle';
  }
};
```

All is good and everything works as intended but I keep getting this warning with a different last line everytime:

(Saw setTimeout with duration Y ms) Y is way higher than my X value

[image: setTimeout Warning]

There is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44603362/setting-a-timer-for-a-long-period-of-time-i-e-multiple-minutes) question but it's not exactly firebase related in my case. (Although I do use firebase to fetch data inside another component but <strike>it shouldn't be the issue</strike>) **IT IS THE ISSUE**

I've looked into [this](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/12981), but most of the solutions either change the "node_modules" or disable the warning and the topic is pretty much outdated.

It would be best If there's a more efficient solution of handling timeouts.

**EDIT: "firebase": "7.13.1" is what's causing the issue when fetching data**

Comment: Where is `getData()` ? Maybe the lag time is too long ‍♂️

Comment: Should be there now, I don't think it's taking a lot of time because the data is being stored locally

Comment: If your `getData()` is an async function, normally, you have to say at your timer as your `getData()` function is an async function.

Example :

```javascript
const timer = setTimeout(() => { // not this
const timer = setTimeout(async () => { // this
```

(and the same for `useEffect`)

Comment: Shouldn't the .then() be enough for that ? If not what do you recommend I change. EDIT: I'll give it a try

Comment: Try to set `async` value for `useEffect` or `timer` or `getData().then()`, it's maybe the problem

Comment: No luck. Still getting the same warning

Comment: Finally, for the moment, I think the two problems is maybe the `async` value not be used, or maybe the timer is too fast. The warning say `Setting a timer for a long time`. Try to set your timer to 30 seconds or other, and see if it works.

Comment: Still nothing. No matter what value I set for the timer, the warning is always there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using a deprecated integration of firebase which was causing this issue, (web config and not .json file)