# timer for a long period problem in react native with firebase

Tags: javascript, react-native

I create function to check if the email and password is exists in firebase and its really works but I got a warning every time

> Setting a timer for a long period of time, i.e. multiple minutes, is a performance and correctness issue on Android as it keeps the timer module awake, and timers can only be called when the app is in the foreground. See
> https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/12981 for more info.

I tried to find a solution but I not found.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you can add this line for disable this warning

```
componentDidMount() { console.disableYellowBox = true; ... }
```

or you can use as below

```
import { YellowBox } from 'react-native';

construct() {
    YellowBox.ignoreWarnings(['Setting a timer']);
}
```

Alyou you should check it same problem with you [detail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44603362/setting-a-timer-for-a-long-period-of-time-i-e-multiple-minutes)

Comment: there is another option for fix it and not just ignore the warning? because some times its take a time to response and when it response the app reloaded

Comment: Is that your development time ?

Answer (score 0):

To fix this issue...

```
Navigate to your node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/Timers/JSTimers.js file.

Look for the variable MAX_TIMER_DURATION_MS

Change its value to 10000 * 1000

Save the changes (with auto format turned off) and re-build your app.
```

Found this answer on https://stackoverflow.com/a/58666279/1532987