# Firebase Functions v.9 - Internal Error after using connectFunctionsEmulator()

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-functions, expo, firebase-tools

I'm trying to setup Emulator for my firebase functions but I receive this annoying internal error. Let's begin with code.

```
  const requestApi = () => {
    const functions = getFunctions(app);
    connectFunctionsEmulator(functions, "127.0.0.1", 5001);
    const helloWorld = httpsCallable(functions, "helloWorld");
    helloWorld()
      .then((result) => {
        console.log(result);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error.message, error.code, error.details);
      });
  };
```

So this function works great, **except when I add** `connectFunctionsEmulator(functions, "127.0.0.1", 5001);` **to it**.

The catch block logs only this useless message.

> internal functions/internal undefined

I also receive warning about **Timer**.

> Setting a timer for a long period of time, i.e. multiple minutes, is a
> performance and correctness issue on Android as it keeps the timer
> module awake, and timers can only be called when the app is in the
> foreground. See https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/12981
> for more info.   (Saw setTimeout with duration 70000ms)

That's all. Pretty strange, isn't it :/ ?

-- **Cloud Function**

```
exports.helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
  res.json({ result: `Check` });
});
```

I add this here cause someone can be curious about this. But, as I mentioned before, function work great when it's deployed. **I'm almost sure that it's client side issue.**

I receive this error no matter what **host** or **port** has been provided. Error is thrown even when **Emulator** is **off**.

Comment: Hi @Adam Szymański, Is `firebase-functions` installed in your project? Have you checked that there are no other app listening to port 5001? For the timer, could you please check this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44603362/setting-a-timer-for-a-long-period-of-time-i-e-multiple-minutes) and see if it helps.

Comment: Firebase Functions installed : "firebase-functions": "^3.16.0", and no other app is working on 5001 port.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, so after almost a week of fighting with this sh!t.

When you use Expo Go like me. You should copy the host address on which you are emulating your app, and use the same address you emulate your functions (or other tools).

[image]

`app.json`

```
{
  "firestore": {
    "rules": "firestore.rules",
    "indexes": "firestore.indexes.json"
  },
  "emulators": {
    "functions": {
      "host": "192.168.0.104",
      "port": 5001
    }
  }
}
```

and final code of `requestApi` function

```
const requestApi = async () => {
    const functions = getFunctions(app);

    connectFunctionsEmulator(functions, "192.168.0.104", 5001);   <--- ADDRESS!!!

    const helloWorld = httpsCallable(functions, "helloWorld");
    helloWorld()
      .then((result) => {
        console.log(result);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error.message, error.code, error.details);
      });
  };
```

Comment: I have been struggling with this for a couple of days, thanks a lot!

Comment: I'm glad I helped :D

Comment: Not entirely related to this question, but in my case, if I do `connectFunctionsEmulator(functions, "localhost", 5001)` as suggested by [the doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/connect_functions#instrument-functions), the function is not triggered. I have to do `connectFunctionsEmulator(functions, "127.0.0.1", 5001)` to make it work.